# Tooltipster not applied to Knockout dynamic elements

Tags: knockout.js, tooltipster

I'm trying to get tooltipster tooltips on some dynamic content generated from knockout. It's a simple list that has a name and edit/delete buttons (which I want the tooltip on). It's populated via a call to Parse.com but I've recreated a simplified version of it.

Here's the HTML:

```
<body>
<button class="tooltip" title="This one works">Static... it works</button>
<ul data-bind="foreach: fields">
    <li>
        <div data-bind="text: name"></div>
        <div class="field_buttons">
            <button class="tooltip" title="Edit this field">Edit</button>      
            <button class="tooltip" title="Delete this field">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
```

And the js:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.fields = ko.observableArray([
        { name: 'Apples' } ,
        { name:'Oranges' } ,
        { name: 'Grapes' },
        ])
}

// apply to static elements
$(".tooltip").tooltipster();

// add some data
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel()); 

// I load some data sometime later and call this again to apply it to the dynamic content - why doesn't this work?
$(".tooltip").tooltipster();
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/rYSH2/10/

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably go for the approach of creating a [bindingHandler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) for tooltipster. It is very easy to do so. Here's a very simplistic bindingHandler which lets you provide options to the tooltipster plugin for each element, if you want to (however, that bindingHandler does not update if the options change, even if they are observable, but look at [the documentation on creating custom bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) if you want to create a binding):

```
ko.bindingHandlers['tooltipster'] = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor){
        $(element).tooltipster(ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()));
    }
};
```

You would then use it like:

```
<button title="tooltip contents" data-bind="tooltipster: { position: 'right' }">Do Stuff</button>
```

or

```
<button data-bind="tooltipster: { content: 'Tooltip contents'}">Do Stuff</button>
```

or, if your bound viewmodel has a property called `tooltip` (with a better written bindingHandler, the tooltip could change if the `tooltip` property is observable and changes):

```
<button data-bind="tooltipster: { content: tooltip }">Do stuff</button>
```

This would avoid having to find elements by classname, it would avoid calling the plugin on the same element multiple times and it would allow you to pass unique (or the same) options to each tooltip, if you want to. It would, for example, also allow you to specify the `content` option, to allow for more advanced scenarios of tooltip content, such as HTML tooltip contents or dynamic tooltip content depending on the current state of the viewmodel (have a look at [the tooltipster API documentation](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/) for all the options you can set).

I have updated your fiddle to use that simple bindingHandler at http://jsfiddle.net/rYSH2/11/. It passes empty options objects to every binding except for the "Delete" button, which has a position specified.

Comment: Robert, thanks a ton for the very detailed explanation. I needed the example in the context of my own project to really understand the ko.unwrap / valueAccessor functions. Cheers!

Comment: I'll add that for some reason, if you call  $(".tooltip").tooltipster(); on $(document).ready() it won't work. Found that after integrating the jsfiddle changes into my project. Just made all my buttons ko bound and that fixed it.